# How to refresh the display rate MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, refresh

[image]

Currently I'm on a MacBook Pro2016 and macOS Monterey ver 12.6.2. My screen is choppy right now, is there any way I can change the rate?

Symptom

[image]

Comment: Define 'choppy'. Is this affecting 'simple' work, or gaming frame rate?

Comment: I don't play the game, when I start the computer it's normal and it only jerks when it's active for a while @Tetsujin

Comment: Take screenshots of Activity Monitor [Applications/Utilities] both CPU & Memory pages.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1M9uHFmuSfaAwa3vv1Fk2feehflMfo6qV?usp=sharing 
I have updated the image to the drive please help me check it includes 1 CPU & memory image and the error I am getting @Tetsujin

Comment: Hmm, it's not memory or CPU. The other picture seems to only be affecting Chrome, not the menu bar. Does it do the same for all apps, including the Finder?

Comment: It affects all screens, whether I use other apps or not

Comment: can you show me the refresh rate?
i think it can help me @Tetsujin

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with refresh rate. It might be a display cabling issue; but that it doesn't seem to affect the menu bar or the Displays control panel leaves me puzzled.

Comment: Could it be a problem with the display cable ports?